# Make code restart if input dosent equal something

Tags: python

Here is my code, i want it to restart when the input doesn't equal something. read below code for more.

```
import colorama
import os
import time

from colorama import Fore

text = Fore.BLUE + """
██████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║
██████╦╝██████╔╝███████║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║
██████╦╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║
╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝
"""
print(text)
inp = input(Fore.WHITE + "What would you like to do?: ")
while inp == 'ping' or 'Ping':
    os.system("cls")
    count = 1
    e = input("Enter IP Address:   ")
    replies = 0
    replies += 1
    hostname = e
    os.system("cls")
    colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
    lr = random.choice(colors)
    lr2 = random.choice(colors)
    lr3 = random.choice(colors)
    lr4 = random.choice(colors)
    print("-" * 100)
    print("=" * 100)
    print("-" * 100)
    while True:
        response = os.system(
            "ping -n 1 " + hostname + " >nul")
        if response == 0:
            print(lr4 + "~ " + lr + hostname + lr2 + " is online!" + lr3 + " [" + str(count) + "]" + lr4 + " ~")
        else:
            print(Fore.BLUE + hostname + Fore.GREEN + " is offline!" + Fore.RED + " [" + str(count) + "]")
        count += 1
        time.sleep(.02)
        continue
while inp != 'ping' or 'Ping':
    print(inp + ' is not a valid command!')
    continue
```

I want it to say that it isn't a valid command and then ask what they want to do again? maybe with a while loop, I don't know.

Comment: Put the code block into a function that you want to restart. Get input and check it outside of the function. If input is incorrect, call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it with a function:

```
import colorama
import os
import time

from colorama import Fore

def runCode(inp):
    os.system("cls")
    count = 1
    e = input("Enter IP Address:   ")
    replies = 0
    replies += 1
    hostname = e
    os.system("cls")
    colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
    lr = random.choice(colors)
    lr2 = random.choice(colors)
    lr3 = random.choice(colors)
    lr4 = random.choice(colors)
    print("-" * 100)
    print("=" * 100)
    print("-" * 100)
    while True:
        response = os.system(
            "ping -n 1 " + hostname + " >nul")
        if response == 0:
            print(lr4 + "~ " + lr + hostname + lr2 + " is online!" + lr3 + " [" + str(count) + "]" + lr4 + " ~")
            else:
                print(Fore.BLUE + hostname + Fore.GREEN + " is offline!" + Fore.RED + " [" + str(count) + "]")
            count += 1
            time.sleep(.02)
            continue

inp=""
while inp != 'ping' or 'Ping':
    text = Fore.BLUE + """
    ██████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗
    ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║
    ██████╦╝██████╔╝███████║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║
    ██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║
    ██████╦╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║
    ╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝
    """
    print(text)
    inp = input(Fore.WHITE + "What would you like to do?: ")
    print(inp + ' is not a valid command!')
    continue
runCode(inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to restart code at the beginning(input), you can write it like that:

```
import colorama
import os
import time

from colorama import Fore

text = Fore.BLUE + """
██████╗░██████╗░░█████╗░██████╗░███████╗███╗░░██╗
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝████╗░██║
██████╦╝██████╔╝███████║██║░░██║█████╗░░██╔██╗██║
██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔══██║██║░░██║██╔══╝░░██║╚████║
██████╦╝██║░░██║██║░░██║██████╔╝███████╗██║░╚███║
╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═════╝░╚══════╝╚═╝░░╚══╝
"""
print(text)

inp = ""

while inp != 'ping' or 'Ping':
    inp = input(Fore.WHITE + "What would you like to do?: ")
    
    if inp != 'ping' or 'Ping':
        print("Try again(or something)")

if inp == 'ping' or 'Ping':
    os.system("cls")
    count = 1
    e = input("Enter IP Address:   ")
    replies = 0
    replies += 1
    hostname = e
    os.system("cls")
    colors = list(vars(colorama.Fore).values())
    lr = random.choice(colors)
    lr2 = random.choice(colors)
    lr3 = random.choice(colors)
    lr4 = random.choice(colors)
    print("-" * 100)
    print("=" * 100)
    print("-" * 100)
    while True:
        response = os.system(
            "ping -n 1 " + hostname + " >nul")
        if response == 0:
            print(lr4 + "~ " + lr + hostname + lr2 + " is online!" + lr3 + " [" + str(count) + "]" + lr4 + " ~")
        else:
            print(Fore.BLUE + hostname + Fore.GREEN + " is offline!" + Fore.RED + " [" + str(count) + "]")
        count += 1
        time.sleep(.02)
        continue
```